# Optimize query to retreive calling clients information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which taking ages in mysql even while it's limited to 7 records.

```
SELECT b.lastname, b.firstname, b.photo, b.id, b.phone_home, a.number, a.calldate 
FROM phonecalls as a 
LEFT JOIN  clients b ON instr(b.phone_home, a.number) 
OR instr(b.phone_work, a.number)
OR instr(b.phone_prive, a.number) 
GROUP BY a.call_id DESC
LIMIT 7
```

**phonecalls table:**

```
call_id        int(11)  
number         varchar(50)
calldate       datetime
```

The phonecalls table contains more than 50.000 records.

**clients table:**

```
id             bigint(20)   
lastname       varchar(200)
firstname      varchar(200)
photo          varchar(255)
phone_home     varchar(50)
phone_work     varchar(50)
phone_prive    varchar(50)
```

The clients table contains more than 2.500 records.

This query is used for call detection of the number calling the data center. When someone is calling, I am searching the clients database, to find if the calling number detected by the system, exists even as part of the 3 phone columns I have in the clients table.
This means if the number 123456 is calling and we have a client with phone_home 0035123456, we need to find it.

Even while limiting only to the last 7 phone calls, it's still super slow.

Any ideas how can I rewrite it to run faster?

Comment: for any kind of help we need EXPLAIN of your query and also then CREATE table inclusive all indexes

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and should raise an exception. (Which will happen with newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: @jarlh I am not getting any error now, so I guess the server runs an older MySQL version

Comment: @nbk Sorry if it's not clear. The client_id and id are the indexes. It's a query used for call detection. It seach if the detected number is found in clients phones.

Comment: my comment describes what is need the explain shows what elemnts are used, the cretae table shows us what us already there, so please add both

Comment: Are all the phone numbers in the CLIENTS table held in the same, consistent format? If not, what are the possible formats? In your example the calling number does not match the CLIENT stored number so what are the rules for unique matching? If we had phone_home 0035123456 and phone_home 0044123456 then obviously 123456 would match twice - so how do we determine which one to match to?

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM phonecalls; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM clients;  and have you considered 
    SELECT b.lastname, b.firstname, b.photo, b.id, b.phone_home, a.number, a.calldate 
    FROM phonecalls as a 
    LEFT JOIN  clients b ON (b.phone_home = a.number 
    OR b.phone_work = a.number
    OR b.phone_prive = a.number) 
GROUP BY a.call_id DESC
LIMIT 7 ?  Query not tested.

Comment: Thanks @Wilson Hauck. Your query run faster: 18 sec but I think it's not searching if the call number is even part of the client's number. For example if we detect 12345 and clients phne number is 00651234567 I still need it to results.

Comment: @WilliamBird Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM phonecalls; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM clients; for analysis.  You may find C) ANALYZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE phonecalls; and D) ANALYZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE clients; improves speed of completion. Then, try this query, SELECT b.lastname, b.firstname, b.photo, b.id, b.phone_home, a.number, a.calldate FROM phonecalls AS a LEFT JOIN clients AS b ON (a.number = b.phone_home OR a.number = b.phone_work OR a.number = b.phone_prive) GROUP BY a.call_id DESC LIMIT 7 - please.  Will still need to work on instr functionality.

Comment: Would you still like to pursue reducing time required to get to your goals?

Comment: @WilsonHauck of course, got something?